# how to separate one object into different parts?

Tags: selection-tools

I do not know exactly what I did, but I am a beginner/noob with Blender. When I select one shape all of the shapes have an orange outline. I don't really know but they are all somehow on the same line/tab. I wanna put them each back to their own tab. Look at the picture to see what I mean. 3 of the shapes have an orange outline when I click "cube" even though it should only be one cube. I wanna make each one its own line again. See how the cones are not selected, each cone has its own separate line/tab. I feel like it is really simple to fix, but it is probably a rare problem so I do not know how to fix it since I am new. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

[image: http://imgur.com/Iv76Abp]

Comment: The most likely reason this happened was because you were still in **Edit Mode** when you added all of the other meshes, so they became part of the original cube.

Answer (score 4):

Try following these steps:

1. Select the object (In this case it is 'Cube')
2. Go into Edit Mode (Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>A</kbd> (Deselect/Select) until everything of that object is selected
4. Press <kbd>P</kbd> -> By loose parts

All of the objects should each have a different 'outline'